# How to setup "Windows" and "menu" keys in pure Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard, tty

When using pure Linux terminal how can I get the Windows (Super) and menu keys events in Emacs?

I have several functions attached to them, they work in GUI mode in Gnome, but in pure terminal I just don't get the events.

Emacs config file bindings:

```
; menu keys
(global-set-key (kbd "<menu>") 'kill-ring-save)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<menu>") 'yank)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<menu>") 'kill-region)

; super-z, super-q (Super = Windows key)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-z") 'point-to-register)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-q") 'jump-to-register)
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding keys is mostly application dependent since any application is free to interpret input keys ad libitum.

[Under `bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) built with the `readline` interpreter library, using `bind` in the form  `bind [-m keymap] -x keyseq:shell-command` would execute shell-command when depressing keyseq.

Emacs has got its own way to define key bindings.
It starts with editing your [initialization file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File)
with [proper instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html).

Comment: I have these keys bound in Emacs. It works in GUI mode. But when I switch to pure console there are no keys passed from the OS. So, I think something is missing on OS/ bash level.

Comment: How can I get what event is passed when I press a key in terminal?

Comment: @user4035 : You have these keys bound in Emacs : Do you mean that they are explicitly setup as part of the init file or only because you presume they are from the fact that it works on some DE ?

Comment: Additionally when writing : "When I switch to pure console", Do you mean when I start Emacs from some tty ?

Comment: They are bound in Emacs config. I added the code to the question. It works in Gnome, KDE, but stops working in pure terminal.

Comment: What if, under console, (re)setting interactively ? (M-x global-set-key RET key cmd RET)

Comment: Manual binding works for Super key, but nothing happens when I try to bind the menu key.